# Strange views issue on upgrade

Tags: views, 8, updating

I'm upgrading a site from 8.4.8 to 8.7.7 via Composer. After a few rounds, things seem pretty good, but I'm stuck on a tricky bit: on `drush updatedb` the process throws an error on Views post-update. Here's the output

> views module :
>     Update dependencies for moved bulk field plugin.
>     Add additional settings to the entity link field and convert node_path usage  to entity_link.
>     Update exposed filter blocks label display to be disabled.
>     Add placeholder settings to string or numeric filters.
>     Rebuild cache to allow placeholder texts to be translatable.
>     Fix cache max age for table displays.
>     Include views data table provider in views dependencies.
>
> Do you wish to run all pending updates? (y/n): y
>   Malformed backend packet [error]
>   Post updating views [ok]
>   Failed: Exception: No entity type for field field_title on view image_paragraph_default in Drupal\views\Plugin\views\HandlerBase->getEntityType() (line 713 of .../docroot/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/HandlerBase.php). [error]
>   The command could not be executed successfully (returned: DRUSH_BACKEND_OUTPUT_START - DRUSH_BACKEND_OUTPUT_END, code: 1) [error]
>   Cache rebuild complete. [ok]
>   Finished performing updates.

So, first of all, am I just missing something obvious? The view is broken in the 8.4 site, too, but I can't figure out how to modify the field *or* remove  the view, since all attempts throw the same error! Is there a way around that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, nevermind -- I realized that I can just remove the view from the config table in the db. Then  all updates are free to proceed. Thanks!